# mysql contrain column values to preset values

Tags: mysql, constraints

I would like to constrain the values of a column, a good analogy is the select form field element, where there is a list of values and only one of these can be selected.

I remember seeing a table's structure with something like this, this is how I became aware that this can be done.

Can anybody write up the mysql query to create a column that has this characteristic?

table name = some_table
column name =some_column
value 1 = value_1
value 2 = value_2

Once this table is created, what is the query I would use to choose one value or another

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do mutually exclusive values with enum, and sets with multiple values using set. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Car
(
   ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
   Model VARCHAR(40),
   Color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'),
   Options SET('power-doors', 'power-windows', 'automatic', 'disc-brakes')
 );
```

Queries work like normal queries.